# Receiving a java.lang nullpointer exception error in Processing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, processing

I am receiving a java.lang nullpointer exception in my processing project, I think it has something to do with the cDistance but I'm not quite sure. I've moved some stuff around and am still getting this error. If anyone has an idea of where I went wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
 class Ball {
  int xpos, ypos;
  int ballDiam;
  color myColor;
  boolean visible = true;
  Ball(int tempdiam, color tempColor) {
    ballDiam=tempdiam;
    myColor=tempColor;
  }

  void update() {
    if (visible) {
      fill(myColor);
      ellipse(xpos, ypos, ballDiam, ballDiam);
    }
  }
} 

Ball hole, gball;//declare a ball object for the golfball and the hole 
float cDistance = dist(gball.xpos, gball.ypos, hole.xpos, hole.ypos);
int click;//to keep track of clicks
String msg;
int steps = 20;
int difx, dify;
Boolean moving = false;
void setup() {
  msg=""; 
  click=0;
  size(800, 400); 
  hole= new Ball(50, #000000);//making the 
  gball = new Ball(35, #ffffff);
} 
void draw() { 
  background(#009900);
  println("the click count is "+click);
  //set the hole ball as a golf hole right in the middle of the green
  hole.xpos = width/2;
  hole.ypos = height/2;
  hole.update();
  if (click==0) {
    //when no click has happened make the gball ball follow the mouse, 
    //after the click the ball will stay at the last position 
    gball.xpos=mouseX;
    gball.ypos=mouseY;
    msg="please place the golf ball";
  }
  else if (click==1) {//prompt the user to click again to shoot
    msg="now click again to shoot";
    difx = gball.xpos-hole.xpos;
    dify = gball.ypos-hole.ypos;
  }
  else if (click==2) {
    cDistance = dist(gball.xpos, gball.ypos, hole.xpos, hole.ypos);
    if (cDistance>hole.ballDiam/2) {
      moving = true;
      gball.xpos-=difx/steps;
      gball.ypos-=dify/steps;
      gball.xpos+=5;
    }
    else {
      moving = false;
      gball.visible=false;
      click=3;
    }
  }
  gball.update();
  textSize(20);
  text(msg, 0, height-5);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (!moving) {
    click++;
  }
}
```

**The stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10573)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10377)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sketch_140421a.<init>(sketch_140421a.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10571)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.  You don't tell us what line produced the error.  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Interesting how `Ball` calls `ellipse`, but I don't see any method declaration...

Comment: This is the error it gives me verbatim. I posted it above.

Comment: the `ellipse` method is provided by the processing framework @Rogue

Answer (score 0):

Your Balls are declared but never initialized here:

```
Ball hole, gball;//declare a ball object for the golfball and the hole 
float cDistance = dist(gball.xpos, gball.ypos, hole.xpos, hole.ypos);
```

==> NPE

You shoul initialize the Balls first with some values, something like:

```
gball = new Ball();
hole = new Ball();
```

In fact you might want to have a constructor for Ball that also sets some values to xpos / ypos or just set some default values, like:

```
class Ball {
   int xpos = 0;
   int ypos = 0;
   //...
```

Comment: Sorry very new processing and coding in general, do they have to be initilized twice? I thought I did that in void setup();?

Comment: you can do that in the setup method that is fine. The problem is the line: `float cDistance = dist(gball.xpos, gball.ypos, hole.xpos, hole.ypos);` which gets executed before the setup method, because it is a field declaration with initial value. You could alternatively just declare `float cDistance;` and during setup() assign it the value _after_ Balls are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Ball#update() calls Ball#eclipse(), which has not been declared, and is therefore null.
You also declare hole and gball of type Ball but never initialise them to new Ball().
I suggest you use an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ, they make trivial bugs such as this much easier to get rid of. Also, post the stacktrace next time.

Comment: The update method is declared in Ball class, take a look ;-) also (maybe I am blind) there is not "eclipse" method called anywhere in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ellipse, fourteenth line down. About the declaration, I missed it. Another thing, it's better to use boolean than Boolean, and any primitive over the wrapped primitive classes since it avoids creating an unnecessary object.